# mssql node issue with named instance

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL) database using the mssql node package. It's not the default instance, and it uses Windows authentication. I'm running Windows 10 x64, the database I'm trying to access was installed by a 3rd party software, and It's a SQL Server 2008 x86 instance. Not sure if this is part of the problem, but in SQL Management Studio, the properties menu says the Operating System for this database is Microsoft Windows NT 6.2 (9200), and the Product is Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition. The Name is 2JBBK72-E7450\SHOPSTREAM, and the same value is listed in the Connection pane under Server. In the Connection pane under Connection is 2JBBK72-E7450\sjay5. I'm not sure if the database is set up under SQL Server authentication or Windows authentication mode. The server properties in SQL Management Studio says both are enabled, but I have no clue what the SQL username and password would be.

Here are the docs for the mssql npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Here is my node.js code:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  // user: 'root',
  // password: 'password',
  // server: 'localhost\\2JBBK72-E7450\\SHOPSTREAM', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
  // server: 'localhost', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
  database: 'ShopMgtDemo',
  // connectionString: 'Server=2JBBK72-E7450\\SHOPSTREAM;Database=ShopMgtDemo;Trusted_Connection=Yes;',
  // connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=2JBBK72-E7450\\SHOPSTREAM;',
    // default connection string: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server={#{server}\\#{instance}};Database={#{database}};Uid={#{user}};Pwd={#{password}};Trusted_Connection={#{trusted}};'
  options: {
    instanceName: '2JBBK72-E7450\\SHOPSTREAM',
    // instanceName: 'SHOPSTREAM',
    trustedConnection: true,
  },
};

// const uri = 'mssql://localhost/2JBBK72-E7450/SHOPSTREAM/ShopMgtDemo?driver=msnodesqlv8';
// const connectionString = 'Driver=msnodesqlv8;Server=(local)\\2JBBK72-E7450\\SHOPSTREAM;Database=ShopMgtDemo;';
  // default connection string: 'Driver=msnodesqlv8;Server=(local)\INSTANCE;Database=database;UID=DOMAIN\username;PWD=password;Encrypt=true;';

sql.connect(config).then(
  () => (
    new sql.Request()
    .query('select * from SM.RepairOrder')
    .then(recordset => console.dir(recordset))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  ),
  err => console.error(err)
)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
{ ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at C:\Users\sjay5\Code\mitchell-sql-feathers\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8.js:222:25
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\sjay5\Code\mitchell-sql-feathers\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\ConnectionWrapper.js:343:21)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:543:15)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:523:5)
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified',
  code: 0 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I had a different driver version; I have 10.0 and it expected 11.0 by default. Additionally, I was able to get the connectionString property of the config to work.

I got it to work with the following code:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server={2JBBK72-E7450\\SHOPSTREAM};Database={ShopMgtDemo};Trusted_Connection={yes}',
};

sql.connect(config).then(
  () => (
    new sql.Request()
    .query('select * from SM.RepairOrder')
    .then(recordset => console.dir(recordset))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  ),
  err => console.error(err)
)
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install the SQL Server Native Client on the windows machine.
Please follow the steps bellow :

Installation instructions can be found under : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065 the section : "**MICROSOFT SQL SERVER CONNECTIVITY FEATURE PACK COMPONENTS**"

To check if the client was properly installed follow the steps bellow :

1. Go to "Start"
2. Click on "Control Panel"
3. Click on "Administrative Tools"
4. Double click on "Data Sources (ODBC)"
5. Click on the "Drivers" tab and make sure there is an item in the
   list with name "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to SQL Server via separated config values (not connection string), you can use this:

```
var config = {
    user: 'devuser',
    password: 'devuser',
    server: 'GRIFF',
    database: 'devdb',
    port: 1433,
    debug: true,
    options: {
        encrypt: false ,
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    }
}
```

So instead of:

> server: 'localhost/SQLEXPRESS'

you must set the instance name in the 'options' section.